# Published WinForm Application unable to find files while they exist

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to publish my C# windows form application, but I'm facing an issue that says the following files couldn't be found:
`ExpiryDate.xml` & `LastDate.xml`

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Resources\LastDate.xml'.
>   File name: 'Resources\LastDate.xml'
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Shebel Ali\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\E24DY4JB.C3R\ZPYV9EGG.4TR\hsar..tion_8b6b4b078cd8a46c_0001.0001_ab66389ef64fd1d7\Resources\ExpiryDate.xml'.
>   File name: 'C:\Users\Shebel Ali\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\E24DY4JB.C3R\ZPYV9EGG.4TR\hsar..tion_8b6b4b078cd8a46c_0001.0001_ab66389ef64fd1d7\Resources\ExpiryDate.xml'

While if I explore the published application folder I can see the files there but with an extension of `LastDate.xml.deploy` and `ExpiryDate.xml.deploy`

Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you add the XML file as a reference to your resources (.resx) file? In this case it won't be added to the output directory.

Comment: How do you "publish" the application? The normal way to create a production build is to build a project as "Release" configuration, and then take everything in the output folder (typically`bin\Release`, or `bin\x86\Release` for 32-bit apps) except the _(appname).vshost.exe_ files.

Comment: @Sefe Yes I've added the files the way u mentioned, any reason/solution please ?

Comment: When you add an XML file to your resources it will become part of the resources. You don't access the file from disc anymore, you access the resource value like `MyResource.MyXMLData`.

Comment: @Nyerguds The way I publish the application is by going the solution exporer, then right click the project, the properties, under the publish tab I click on "Publish Now" and that's it, this will allow me to "install" the application rather than just using the .exe file as the way you're talking about, am I right?!

Comment: Go to your xml files properties, and check the _Compilation action_ and _Copy in the results directory_ properties

Comment: I stopped using that way ages ago. Much more straightforward to just make a zipfile of the final program, or your own installer.

Comment: @Pikoh i think you mean the "Copy to Output Directory" property, I already set it to "Copy Always"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have referenced your *LastDate.xml* file from a `.resx` file in your application. In this case the *content* of your XML file is turned into a resource during build and you can access the XML data from the resources (assuming in your example that the resource file is *MyXmlResources.resx* and the resource name in that file is *LastDate*):

```
var lastDate = MyXmlResources.LastDate;
```

There is no need to load the XML data from disc and you also shouldn't do it, because your XML file will not be on the target directory.

Comment: Thank Sefe, I got your point now, but I still have doubt about what u have said at the end, if I set the `xml` file's property "Copy to Output Directory" to be "Copy Always", this will not allow to put the file in the target directory?!

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: It will be there _upon build_, but _publish_ can be a different story. Anyway, there is no point in copying the file when you have it in your resources.